# I am not able to perform RANK function in Sybase ASE

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase, rank

while using RANK () OVER(Partition by column_1 order by column_2 asc) as Rank

it says incorrect syntax near "OVER".

Any alternatives for calculating rank in sybase ase??

Thanks in Advance.

CODE:

```
SELECT
BRN AS br_name, 
SUM(TGAB) AS gross_amt_base
from (
SELECT
    MB.BNAC AS BRN,
    MT.TGAB * MTTM.MQR AS TGAB
FROM
    dbo.MB MB,
    dbo.MT MT,
    dbo.MTTM MTTM,
    dbo.MPPGTT MPPGTT
WHERE
    MT.TEI IN (SELECT MAC.AAEI
                                  FROM
                                      dbo.MAC MAC,
                                      dbo.MEA MEA,
                                      dbo.MC MAC
                                  WHERE
                                      MAC.AASN = 'JPFA 5201   ' AND
                                      MAC.AL = 'en-us' AND
                                      MAC.CL = 'en-us' AND
                                      MAC.AAEI = MEA.ea_id AND
                                      MAC.CC = MEA.EBC) AND
    MT.TED >= '2012-03-01 00:00:00.000' AND
    MT.TED <= '2012-03-30 00:00:00.000' AND
    MT.TBC NOT IN
    (
        0,
        2,
        99,
        752,
        1000001,
        2000002,
        390003431
    )
    AND
    MB.BL = 'en-tx' AND
    (MT.TCI != 'Y' OR
     MT.TCD > '2012-03-30 00:00:00.000' OR
     MT.TCD < '2012-03-01 00:00:00.000' OR
     (MT.TOED < '2012-03-01 00:00:00.000' OR
      MT.TOED > '2012-03-30 00:00:00.000') AND
     NOT MT.TOED IS NULL) AND
    MTTM.MLL = 'en-us' AND
    MTTM.MTC = 7000 AND
    MTTM.MTP = 'Y' AND
    MTTM.MGO IN
    (
        'Purchases',
        'Sales'
    )
    AND
    ISNULL (MTTM.MAWF,
            'LINK') = ISNULL (MT.TAWF,
                              'LINK') AND
    MT.TGAB > 0 AND
    MB.br_code = MT.TBC AND
    MPPGTT.PTTC = MT.tr_tt_code AND
    MTTM.mtttm_tt_code = MPPGTT.PTTC) AS A
    GROUP BY BRN
```

Comment: You need to leave a space between OVER and (Partiton...

Answer (score 1):

If your version of Sybase doesn't support window functions (which is what the error message suggests), then you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select 1 + count(*)
        from t t2
        where t2.column_1 = t.column_1 and
              t2.column_2 < t.column_2
       ) as therank
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon! Now my error is "Implicit conversion from univarchar to decimal not allowed". I guess i need to use convert function as column_1 is univarchar and column_2 is float.

Comment: @Novice_Techie . . . This should generate no conversion errors.  The columns are being compared to themselves -- so the types are the same.

Comment: i have pasted my actual code over. I Need to have a rank on gross_Amt_base.

Comment: @Novice_Techie . . . Your error is not related to your question about calculating a rank.

Comment: Yes gordon...i have pasted my code above. I need to calculate Rank based on gross_amt_base order by br_name asc.

Answer (score 1):

Analytical rank() function is available in Sybase IQ, but not in ASE, so for the latter you'll have to hack it, Gordon-style.